# Gibraltar & surroundings to Morocco with a bicycle

Tags: spain, ferries, morocco

What are the options and prices to get from Gibraltar and southern Spain to Morocco with a bicycle?

I've found some ferries that operates there, however all of them cost over 35 euros round trip. Is there any cheaper option?

Comment: Swimming? What price do you want to pay?! 35 euros is a good price!!

Comment: Well, maybe for people that earn in euros... For example 35 euros costs ferry Istanbul-Bandirma RT at maximum and it is over 100 km one way. Besides flights with Ryanair from Spain to Morocco costs less when bought in advance (without the cost of bicycle). So, that is why it seems a lot to me.

Comment: I understand, but Spain is expensive. Some years ago, the price was even higher :(

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, Ivan is right. Your options are to pay for the ferry and take the bike or fly and buy a bike when you get there. I guess it's really up to you and how attached to/expensive your bike is.

The other option is to maybe hang out around the docks for a few days and ask ships if they're heading across and will give you a lift, however I would recommend entering Morocco legally, so you'll need to get dropped off where there is an immigration office (so essentially where the Ferry drops you). To be honest if you want to travel you have to spend some money and 35 euro is not really that much to get from one country to another with a bicycle.